# How do I use address data in Calc to populate labels in Writer in the OpenOffice.org suite?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer, openoffice-base

I have a list of mailing addresses in a calc spreadsheet - one column per line in the address.  I want to print them out on a sheet of labels.  When I open a new labels document, there doesn't appear to be an option to set the source of the label text as a spreadsheet.  The only options it gives me for Database are Bibliography and EvolutionLocal.  Do I need to find a way to get the data into one of these?

It seems it really shouldn't be very complicated.  I just can't figure out where I need to go to do it.

I think I have a middle-step now, but I'm not sure.  I've created a database in base and imported the mailing list from calc into base.  Now that mailing list database shows up as a Database option when I create a new sheet of labels.  The problem is now that it's not reading the contents, even when I press the Synchronize button.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OpenOffice's mail merge is pretty much useless.  It isn't easy to use, nor does it necessarily work.  You have to use their field names, or you can't use it at all.  Basically, just steal Office and use that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is commonly called "mail merge". OpenOffice.org can do a mail merge based on addresses in a Calc document, as you describe.

There is a good tutorial in the OOo wiki:

[Using Mail Merge](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_Mail_Merge)

I recommend you try this. If you still have problems, edit your question, or ask a new question. Good luck!

Comment: OpenOffice's mail merge is rather unintuitive, at least to me. Please review seleske's link. And these tips may help.
Register the database.
Set up the mailing labels.
Open the mailing label doc. Choose NO to update all links quest.
Print the mailing labels document. In the dialog that appears, choose the data source (your database table or query). 
Choose print-to-file option until you get it right. 
When opening the doc containing the labels choose NO to update all links.